# I want to know if this program runs 24/7 will the operating system get overloaded?

Tags: c, data-structures

There are no syntax errors but i want to know if this program runs 24/7 will the operating system get overloaded? And how to test memory ? I mean how many of unused variables are there ? I wrote this code in visual studio an there can be some changes.

```
struct video{
    char category[10];
    long long int rating;
};

int main(void){
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    while (1) {
        struct video* gaming = (struct video*) malloc(sizeof(*gaming));
        struct video* music = (struct video*) malloc(sizeof(*music));
        struct video* vlog = (struct video*) malloc(sizeof(*vlog));

        strcpy_s(gaming->category, 7, "Gaming");
        strcpy_s(music->category, 6, "Music");
        strcpy_s(vlog->category, 5, "Vlog");

        gaming->rating = rand() % 10000000 + 1;
        music->rating = rand() % 10000000 + 1;
        vlog->rating = rand() % 10000000 + 1;

        printf("Category: %s Rating: %lld",gaming->category,gaming->rating);
        printf("Category: %s Rating: %lld",music->category,music->rating);
        printf("Category: %s Rating: %lld",vlog->category,vlog->rating);

        Sleep(3000);
        system("cls");

        free(gaming);
        free(music);
        free(vlog);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you move `srand` out of the `while` loop, although as you delay for 3 seconds in each loop, you may not immediately notice the lack of randomness.

Comment: "*And how to test memory*" Simple approach (not suitable for planes, etc ...): let it run a minute, an hour, a day, a week and regularly consult the task-manager's info on the program's process?

Comment: It is possible that the heap may end up fragmented - and notice you do not `free` memory in the reverse sequence of the allocation

Comment: I don't see any reason to keep allocating and freeing the same structures each time through the loop.  Instead, why not allocate them once, outside the loop, and set the category once, outside the loop.  The only thing you need to do to them inside the loop is change the rating.

Comment: You need to create structure again after deleting

Comment: Right - so don't delete them.  That wasn't obvious?  I would say free them after exiting the loop, but since this loop never exits, there's no need.

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  Strongly suggest also posting the `#include` statements.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer. Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing the casting AND add the check the returned values.

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `gaming->rating = rand() % 10000000 + 1;`  the `+` operator has a higher precedence than the `%` operator.  The result of this kind of line will not be what you intended.  Suggest adding parens, as in:  `gaming->rating = (rand() % 10000000) + 1;`  so the desired sequence of operations is performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the OS won't get "overloaded".

There's a 3 second sleep on each iteration of the loop, and there is very little going on in each iteration, so CPU usage isn't a problem.   You're not overstepping any memory bounds, and you free all memory you allocate after use, so memory usage isn't a problem.